# Ruby on rails: mock and stub library

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What the best library to use for mock, stub... in ROR application?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Mocha](http://mocha.rubyforge.org/) is a quite nice mocking and stubbing library for Ruby.

Have a look at the [example usages](http://mocha.rubyforge.org/examples/misc.html).

```
def test_mocking_a_class_method
  product = Product.new
  Product.expects(:find).with(1).returns(product)
  assert_equal product, Product.find(1)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

[RSpec](http://rspec.info/documentation/mocks/) comes with mocking capabilities. There is also [FlexMock](http://flexmock.rubyforge.org/) and [rr](http://github.com/btakita/rr)